# How to insert nodes with labels and aroperties in Python client for Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I've been trying to figure out how to use a Python client to insert nodes into my graph database. I need to add nodes that might already exist or might not exist yet, along with their labels and properties.

I've gone through the Memgraph documentation, but I couldn't find a clear answer on how to do this.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Check if a node exists.
2. If it does, update its properties.
3. If it doesn't, create the node with specific labels and properties.